# How to subtract two DataFrame columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do some basic calculations inside a pandas dataframe, but apparently pandas ignores empty rows. So let's assume my dataframe looks as follows:

```
ColA ColB
11    6
7
```

Then doing df["ColC"] = df["ColA"].subtract(df["ColB"]) will yield

```
ColA ColB ColC
11    6    5
7
```

Whereas I would want that ColC also has a "7" in this case.

What's the best way to do these calculations with DataFrames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
df["ColC"] = df["ColA"].subtract(df["ColB"], fill_value=0)
```